# Error when using lmer but not lme (specifying nested data in random-effects structure)

Tags: lme4-nlme, nested-data

I have a dataset with participants' scores on three exams. Each participant completed each of the three exams. So the dataset looks something like (for a total of 945 rows):

```
SubjectCode    Exam    Score
1              A       70
1              B       44
1              C       80
2              A       62
2              B       50
2              C       89
```

I can run the following model without problem, using the `nlme` library:

```
lme(LD ~ 1, random = ~1|SubjectCode/Exam, data = ld_melted, method = "ML")
```

However, when I try the same with the `lme4` library, I get an error:

```
lmer(LD ~ 1 + (1|SubjectCode/Exam), data = ld_melted)

Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
```

Firstly, I don't understand the error. My dataset consists of 945 rows: 315 students * 3 exams. So it would seem that "the number of levels of each grouping factor" is 315 for `SubjectCode`, and 3 for `Exam`, both of them lower then the number of observations (945).

Secondly, the [GLMM FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) states that model specifications are used both by `lme4` and `nlme`. So I also don't understand why one, but not the other, throws an error.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `(1|SubjectCode/Exam)` is equivalent to `(1|SubjectCode) +  (1|SubjectCode:Exam)`. The interaction `SubjectCode:Exam` has 945 levels and you have 945 rows. So `lme4` is right in complaining. No idea why `nlme` does not.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. What would in your opinion then be the correct way to specify this model, considering the fact that I have repeated measures? (This is supposed to be a null model without fixed effects; I'll add the fixed effects later when I know that the null model is correct)

Comment: `LD ~ 1 + (1|SubjectCode)`. You don't need random effect for Student/Exam if you only have 1 observation per Student/Exam combination.